# Segmentation fault occurs only under release configuration

Tags: c++, qt

For some odd reason, my application likes to break on me when I switch to release and run it outside of my debugger.  Here's what works for me, and here's what doesn't

(Qt Creator is the IDE)

- Debugging with debug configuration - *ok*
- Running with debug configuration - *ok*
- Debugging with release configuration - *ok*
- Running with release configuration - *application crash*

My UI is one project, and the core for some stuff as a separate dependency.  On Windows (compiling with MSVCC), I hit a menu button, which eventually calls down to a function.  In that function, the app breaks on adding a new element to a vector.  e.g:

```
str *x = new str();
str *y = new str();
/* ...set some of x & y's members... */
vector.push_back(x); // works fine
vector.push_back(y); // causes crash
```

If I comment out the line `vector.push_back(y);`, the app continues no problem until the app leaves the event scope (i.e. the end of `OnMenuButtonClick`).  On OS X, it's similar to the issue of adding an element to a vector, except I have:

```
std::vector<foo *> SomeFunction()
{
   std::vector<foo *> returningVector;
   /* do stuff */
   std::vector<foo *> goo = GetFooObjects();
   for (int i = 0; i < goo.size(); i++)
   {
       returningVector.push_back(goo[i]); // breaks here
   }
}
```

So what are some causes of this strange behavior without a debugger attached and not under debug configuration?  I've checked to make sure all of my variables are initialized, so I'm stumped.  If you want to view the code above, the first part can be located [here](https://github.com/landr0id/Up/blob/windows/FATX/FATX/Drive.cpp#L636), and the second part [here](https://github.com/landr0id/Up/blob/windows/FATX/FATX/Drive.cpp#L759).  Please forgive anything you see as "bad", and if you have suggestions that you just can't contain, then please do message me on GitHub.

Edit:

I looked more into it, and found out exactly what's causing the problem, but don't know how to fix it.  This is the function where my app crashes (on OS X):

```
vector<Drive *> Drive::GetFATXDrives( bool HardDisks )
{
    vector<Drive *> Return;
    if (HardDisks)
    {
        vector<DISK_DRIVE_INFORMATION> Disks = GetPhysicalDisks();
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)Disks.size(); i++)
        {
            DISK_DRIVE_INFORMATION ddi = Disks.at(i);
            // First, try reading the disk way
            Streams::xDeviceStream* DS = NULL;
            try
            {
                char path[0x200] = {0};
                wcstombs(path, ddi.Path, wcslen(ddi.Path));
                DS = new Streams::xDeviceStream(ddi.Path);
            }
            catch (xException& e)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (DS == NULL || DS->Length() == 0 || DS->Length() < HddOffsets::Data)
            {
                // Disk is not of valid length
                continue;
            }
            DS->SetPosition(HddOffsets::Data);

            // Read the FATX partition magic
            int Magic = DS->ReadInt32();
            // Close the stream
            DS->Close();

            // Compare the magic we read to the *actual* FATX magic
            if (Magic == FatxMagic)
            {
                Drive *d = new Drive(Disks.at(i).Path, Disks.at(i).FriendlyName, false);
                Return.push_back(d);
            }
        }
    }

    vector<Drive *> LogicalDisks = GetLogicalPartitions();
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)LogicalDisks.size(); i++)
    {
        Return.push_back(LogicalDisks.at(i));
    }

    return Return;
}
```

If I change `if (HardDisks)` to `if (HardDisks = false)`, the app works just fine.  So, I looked into that scope and discovered that after `vector<DISK_DRIVE_INFORMATION> Disks = GetPhysicalDisks();`, the heap gets corrupt or something like that.  I noticed this because in the debugger, after that function is called, my `HardDisks` bool changes to "false", which wasn't what it was before.

Here is `GetPhysicalDisks`:

```
vector<Drive::DISK_DRIVE_INFORMATION> Drive::GetPhysicalDisks( void )
{
    // RIGHT AFTER this vector is initialized, everything goes to hell
    vector<Drive::DISK_DRIVE_INFORMATION> ReturnVector;

DIR *dir;
dirent *ent;
dir = opendir("/dev/");
if (dir != NULL)
{
    // Read the shit
    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        // Check the directory name, and if it starts with "disk" then keep it!
        QRegExp exp("disk*");
        exp.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::Wildcard);
        exp.setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
        if (exp.exactMatch(ent->d_name))
        {
            DISK_DRIVE_INFORMATION curdir;
            memset(curdir.FriendlyName, 0, sizeof(curdir.FriendlyName));
            memset(curdir.Path, 0, sizeof(curdir.Path));

            char diskPath[0x50] = {0};
            sprintf(diskPath, "/dev/r%s", ent->d_name);

            mbstowcs(curdir.Path, diskPath, strlen(diskPath));

            int device;
            if ((device = open(diskPath, O_RDONLY)) > 0)
            {
#ifdef __linux
                hd_driveid hd;
                if (!ioctl(device, HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, &hd))
                {
                    swprintf(curdir.FriendlyName, strlen(hd) * 2, L"%hs", hd.model);
                }
#elif defined __APPLE__
                mbstowcs(curdir.FriendlyName, ent->d_name, strlen(ent->d_name));
#endif
                ReturnVector.push_back(curdir);
            }
        }
    }
}
    return ReturnVector;
}
```

Comment: Can you put your push_back in a try .. catch block to see if you get an exception or just crash?

Comment: No dice.  If it did work though, I'd still actively seek the root cause, since it's silencing the issue and not necessarily solving it.

Comment: It is not meant to silence the issue, but if you can display the exception message, it should help you a little.

Comment: I probably should have stated before that I attached the debugger before the crash, and that's how I discovered that it's a segmentation fault.  "Signal received: The inferior stopped becaues it received a signal from the Operating system.  Signal name: SIGSEGV, Signal Meaning: Segmentation faul".  I also forgot to say thank you in my first reply.

Comment: Is vector being accessed by multiple threads ?

Comment: Your app crash on push_back method, which only push a pointer to your list or vector which is a really small data. If you put your push_back in a try catch block do you receive a bad_alloc exception? If you do not receive an exception and you are still crashing that means the problem is not there. I had this kind of bug (working under debugging but crashing without it) and the problem came from the UI part, the UI thread was trying to access data that was not finished to be initialized. Under debugging the data was already initialized but without the data was not ready. Hope that could help.

Comment: that actually does sound quite plausible that it's something from the UI, except it's not multithreaded for this part of the application.  The try/catch threw the same thing, but this time I attached Visual Studio as well, which gave me an access violation error.

Comment: Try on Linux or OS X if valgrind's memcheck finds some issue like invalid reads/writes.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Valgrind was useful, spit out: http://pastebin.com/VnJZdnun

Comment: Is Drive::GetFATXDrives(bool) the GetFooObjects from above? Please paste its implementation. My first guess would be that you return a somehow invalid vector object, e.g. returning a temporary vector object by const ref. instead of value.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld the full function can be found [here](https://github.com/landr0id/Up/blob/osx/FATX/FATX/Drive.cpp#L713), and is called [here](https://github.com/landr0id/Up/blob/osx/FATX/FATX/Drive.cpp#L713).  Through the use of `qDebug`, I'm able to see that the application reaches line 759 and breaks there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this isn't a real answer as to what *happened*, I did find a way to fix the problem.  Looking at my edit above, I edited my `Drive::GetFATXDrives` function like so:

```
vector<Drive *> Drive::GetFATXDrives( bool HardDisks )
{
    // Initialize Disks vector up here
    vector<DISK_DRIVE_INFORMATION> Disks;
    // Call the function to get the hard disks
    if (HardDisks)
        Drive::GetPhysicalDisks(Disks);

    vector<Drive *> ReturnVector;
    if (HardDisks)
    {
        Streams::xDeviceStream* DS = NULL;
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)Disks.size(); i++)
        {
            /* ... */
        }
        if (DS)
        {
            DS->Close();
            delete DS;
        }
    }

    vector<Drive *> LogicalDisks = GetLogicalPartitions();
    for (int i = 0; i < LogicalDisks.size(); i++)
    {
        ReturnVector.push_back(LogicalDisks[i]);
    }

    return ReturnVector;
}
```

And my `Drive::GetPhysicalDisks` function now takes a `vector<DISK_DRIVE_INFORMATION>` reference instead of returning one.  Seemed to make my program work just fine after that.